# GLSL variable not passing from vertex to fragment shader

Tags: glsl, vulkan

I'm getting a strange error when trying to pass a float from my vertex to the fragment shader.

Vertex shader:

```
#version 450

out float someFloat;

void main() {
someFloat = 1.0;
// some code ...
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
#version 450

in float someFloat;

void main() {

// some code using someFloat ...
}
```

This won't work and always pass zero, while this works:

Vertex shader:

```
 #version 450

 layout (location = 0) out float someFloat;

 void main() {

    someFloat = 1.0;

    // some code ...
 }
```

Fragment shader:

```
#version 450

layout (location = 0) in float someFloat;

void main() {

// Some code using someFloat ...
}
```

But how can I do this without having to use locations ?

Comment: Are the shaders linked together into the same program or are you using multiple programs via a pipeline object?

Comment: Im using Vulkans' graphics pipeline. I also have a vec3 array that can be passed with in and out without a problem.

Comment: "*Im using Vulkans' graphics pipeline*" Then you need to say that, as that is very important to why your code isn't working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [KHR_vulkan_glsl](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/GLSL/blob/master/extensions/khr/GL_KHR_vulkan_glsl.txt), which governs the compilation of GLSL into SPIR-V for Vulkan:

> When generating SPIR-V, all `in` and `out` qualified user-declared (non built-in) variables and blocks (or all their members) **must have a shader-specified `location`**. Otherwise, a compile-time error is generated.

Emphasis added. GLSL is not identical between OpenGL and Vulkan.

This of course is because SPIR-V doesn't allow GLSL's resource matching between stages by name (since SPIR-V variables don't have to have names). It only does it by location. And rather than require the compiler to generate locations that will somehow match locations specified by names in other stages, it simply requires users to spell out the locations directly in the shader.

You should have gotten an error from your GLSL compiler.

Comment: Didnt know that OpenGL and Vulkan GLSL were different, thanks for clarifying and helping

Answer (score -1):

You need use a varying variable.

Vertex shader:

```
varying float someFloat;

void main() {
  someFloat = 1.0;
  // some code ...
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
varying float someFloat;

void main() {
  // some code using someFloat ...
}
```

Comment: Varyings have been deprecated as of GLSL 4.20, so if you're doing Vulkan (and modern GLSL) you should stay away from them and go with in/out qualifiers with locations as Nical Bolas pointed out.